# Need to have N txt files created, np.savetxt

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, jupyter, txt

for a math paper I need to make N slices and output them to as many different txt files as there are slices made. Everything should be saved in TXT. I mean, I need to write each new step of the cycle to a new file.

```
N=10
j=1
for i in range (1,N):
    df_step=df2 [j::N]
    j+=1
    np.savetxt(r'c:\Data\step.txt', df_step, fmt='%s')
```

need each step of the loop to be saved to a file named step_1, step_2, step_3, ...., step_i.
`np.savetxt(r'c:\Data\step.txt', df_step, fmt='%s')`
What should i change here?

---

Comment: Use `np.savetxt(fr'c:\Data\step_{i}.txt', df_step, fmt='%s')`. And you can replace `j` by `i`, it's useless to have two counters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `df_step` is what you want, you can use the `.to_csv` function call for dataframes:

```
for i in range (1,N):
    df_step=df2[j::N]
    j+=1
    df_step.to_csv("Step_"+str(i)+".txt")
```

You can specify formats and separators as well in the function